# Friendly Intranet Addresses

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Relativly new to IIS.

I'm attempting to set up multiple sites in my Intranet on one server. The server already has SharePoint Installed on it and has a binding *:80. So when I type //ServerName I get the home page of SharePoint. I get how that works.

I set up a new site in IIS and set the Binding to *:30015. On a remote machine if I type //ServerName:30015 in a web browser, I get the new site. Awesome, working as intended.

**My Questions:**

1. Can/How do i set it up so that I can type //DivisionAppName or //Division.AppName and have it resolve itself to //ServerName:30015?
2. Is this something I have to register with my Company's DNS server? I hope not, getting my corprate IT to assist is a nightmare.

**What I tried:** I have added Bindings with the Host Name filled in with both DivisionAppName or Division.AppName and port 30015 but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mostly on the right track.

You need both DNS and IIS configured.  In order to test this, keep your IIS settings as described and edit your `hosts` file locally so that `DivisionAppName` will route to the correct box.

However, you'll still need the browser to put in the port:  `//DivisionAppName:30015`

If you don't want to include the port number in the "friendly" URL, you can actually have IIS listen to port 80 and differentiate based on hostname.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to configure DNS to get the custom host name to route properly, and IIS to accept requests to that hostname for your website.

If IIS is setup to accept the host name, then you can configure your website to listen on 80.

Answer (score 2):

One solution: You will need to change the default binding for `*:80` on the Sharepoint site to include a host header. This will allow you to have an additional website also bound to `*:80` with a different host header, thus eliminating the need for the port number to be entered in the browser.

For example:

Modify the current binding of `*:80` to include `ServerName` as the host header
on the new site add a binding of `*:80` with a new host header `DivisionAppName`. 
Have corporate IT enter a CNAME record in DNS pointing `DivisionAppName` to `ServerName`.

Another solution that would allow you to avoid DNS changes and enter a URL like `ServerName/appname` would be to create a virtual directory at the root of the site in IIS called `appname` and place your app in there.